# Problemas conectando PHP a MySQL en localhost

Tags: php, mysql

He realizado otra conexión antes igual con otra base de datos, al cambiar de base de datos me da este error y no veo el error por ningún lado:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for localhost failed: Host desconocido

Éste es el contenido de `config.php`:

```
$nombre_servidor = "localhost";
$nombre_usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$nombre_base_datos = "usu";
```

Ésta es la conexión:

```
<?php
private static $conexion;

        public static function abrir_conexion(){
            if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
                try{
                   include "config.inc.php";
                    print "hola";
                  
                    self::$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host= $nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos; port=3307; charset=utf8", $nombre_usuario, $password);
                    self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    // Si ponemos lo siguiente comentado no funciona
                    // self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER utf8");
                }catch(PDOException $ex){
                    print "<db>"."ERROR: " . $ex -> getMessage() . "<br>";
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
```

Cuando llamo a abrir conexión me escribe el *hola*, pero me salta después el mensaje de error.

Aquí Localhost:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el sistema operativo del servidor y la salida de un `nslookup localhost` o un `dig +short localhost` o `ping -c 2 localhost`? ¿Puedes probar a cambiar `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Si pongo 127.0.0.1 en vez de localhost me sale error con la IP ya q resuelve el nombre, los dos comandos siguiente no me funcionan ya que es windows 10

Comment: Disculpa, ' nslookup localhost` es multiplataforma, debería funcionar en Linux, MacOS y Windows. Y `ping localhost` (sin el `-c 2`) también funciona en Windows. ¿Está funcionando bajo Windows usando WSL, instalación manual o algún paquete "todo-en-uno" como XAMPP, WampServer, etc? Y, exactamente, ¿qué mensaje de error te da cuando pones la IP? Tu explicación no me aclara demasiado qué ocurre.

Comment: Establecido en la pregunta

Comment: Ya he encontrado el error. Redactando la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en la siguiente línea:

```
self::$conexion = new PDO(
    "mysql:host= $nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos; port=3307; charset=utf8",
    $nombre_usuario,
    $password
);
```

El nombre del equipo debería ir inmediatamente después del símbolo `=`, pero has dejado un espacio en blanco que se está incluyendo en el nombre del equipo que se está tratando de resolver por DNS.

Debes eliminar ese espacio en blanco (igual que haces con `dbname=`) para que se solucione el problema:

```
self::$conexion = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$nombre_servidor; dbname=$nombre_base_datos; port=3307; charset=utf8",
    $nombre_usuario,
    $password
);
```

Si ves el código fuente de la página que ha generado el error notarás que hay dos espacios en blanco en `getaddrinfo for  localhost failed` (entre `for` y `localhost`), pero al ver el resultado en el navegador web éste fusiona ambos espacios en blanco en uno único.

Los mensajes de error en diferentes versiones de PHP son (todos empiezan en común con `ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005]`):

### 8.1

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for  localhost failed: Name or service not known
```

### 8.0, 7.4 y 5.6

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

### 5.4

```
Unknown MySQL server host ' localhost' (110)
```

Comment: Solucionado, igualmente ese espacio lo había añadido yo por q no me funcionaba antes, así que no entiendo que me debió suceder si actualizaba pagina con ctrl+f5